# How to override?

Tags: java, overriding

> ```
> package wr3;
>
> public class Person {
>     private String name;
>     private String id;
>     private String bday;
>     private String address;
>
>     public String getName(){
>         return name;
>     }
>
>     public String getID(){
>         return id;
>     }
>
>     public String getBday(){
>         return bday;
>     }
>
>     public String getAdd(){
>         return address;
>     }
>
>
>     public void equals(){
>         super.equals(id);
>     }
>     @Override
>     public String toString(){
>         return(name + bday + id + address);
>     }
> }
> ```

---

> ```
> package wr3;
>
> public class Test {
>     public static void main(String[] args){
>         String name = "Claude Rhay Torre";
>         String name2 = "Bea Señerpida";
>         String id = "10302993";
>         String id2 = "11102825";   
>         String bday = "06/201993";
>         String bday2 = "11/17/1994";
>         String address = "BF Better Living Basak LLC";
>         String address2 = "F Martyr St Poblacion LLC";
>         boolean eq;
>
>         System.out.println(name.toString());
>         System.out.println(id.toString());
>         System.out.println(bday.toString());
>         System.out.println(address.toString());
>         System.out.println();
>
>         System.out.println(name2.toString());
>         System.out.println(id2.toString());
>         System.out.println(bday2.toString());
>         System.out.println(address2.toString());
>
>
>         eq = id.equals(id2);
>         System.out.println("\nDo they have the same ID number? " + eq );
>
>     }
> }
> ```

So I have this code.
And I also have this problem.

- A. Object class

  1. Study the Object class in the java.lang package.
  2. Understand all its methods.
  3. Create a Person class with the requirements:
      a. Implement encapsulation
      b. The fields are: name, ID (identification number), birthday, and
         address.
      c. A method that will override the equals( ) method of Object class.
         Two persons are equal if they have the same id.
      d. A method that will override the toString( ) method of Object
         class. It displays the id, name, birthday, and address of a Person
         object.
  4. Create a test class to create Person objects and call the equals( ) and toString( ) methods appropriately.

My question is, are these two classes even related?
What I mean, is my **"toString" and "equal"** method called on my **Test class** the one that is in my **Person's class**? Or is it the **"toString" and "equal"** methods on the Object class?

How can I override the **equals** and **toString** class in the Object class?

Comment: Your `Test` class doesn't create `Person` objects...

Comment: Wouldn't executing the methods in question answer that question essentially immediately? You override methods by duplicating their signature.

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't get it... can you explain it in details please? :(

Comment: @ClaudeRhay Create a method called `public boolean equals(Object o)` in your class; you have overridden [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29). Create a method called `public String toString()` in your class; you have overridden [toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When inheriting a method from another class (such as `public String toString()` from `Object`), all you have to do to override it is define your own `public String toString()` in your class. You have actually done that in your code and you have successfully overridden `toString()` for all instances of `Person`.

The reason you're not seeing the result you might expect is that the `toString()` and `equals()` methods you are calling are from the `String` class, not from your `Person` class. This is because you are calling them on `String` objects, not `Person` objects - and those two classes are not related hierarchically (apart from their common `Object` ancestor).

Your `Test` could be like this, instead:

```
    Person p1 = new Person();
    p1.name = "Claude Rhay Torre";
    p1.id = "10302993";
    p1.bday = "06/20/1993";
    p1.address = "BF Better Living Basak LLC";

    Person p2 = new Person();
    p2.name2 = "Bea Señerpida";
    p2.id2 = "11102825";   
    p2.bday2 = "11/17/1994";
    p2.address2 = "F Martyr St Poblacion LLC";

    System.out.println(p1.toString());
    System.out.println(p2.toString());
```

Comment: Can you tell me on how to do inheritance? Like, redo my code? :/ I just don't seem to get it. How can I get them related?

Comment: @ClaudeRhay For various reasons, `String` is marked as `final` by the designers of Java, which means that you can't make a subclass of `String` at all.

Comment: Oh okay, I seem to get it now. Then how can I make them inherit on my Person's class?

Comment: @ClaudeRhay You don't have to inherit anything. All you have to do is simply create `Person` instances (with `new Person()`) in your `Test` and keep it in a variable of type `Person` (not `String`). Then set the properties of those `Person` instances with the values you already have there in your code and just call `toString()` on the `Person`-type variables.

Comment: Oooooooooooooooh! Now I get it! Hahahahahahahahaha! OmG i'm such a noob. :))))))) Do I lack methods on my Person's class? like set something? Or a constructor perhaps? And can you give me something like an example for my Test class?

Comment: @ClaudeRhay See my edit, it should get you started on how it works. Of course, once you've done this you'll eventually have to start making getters and setters and the other things you mentioned.

Comment: I have a bit of a question. In your given code, how can I access my fields when they're private?

Comment: Or how can I assign my setters and getters?

Comment: @ClaudeRhay You don't directly access fields that are private. You write them and read them using getters and setters which, despite their fancy name, are nothing more than regular methods.